# Azure stream analytics split at comma

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub, azure-stream-analytics

I have an input to my stream analytics job as a CSV string such as follows:

```
jon,41,111 treadmill lane,07831231123,aa,bb,123...etc.
```

I'd like to sort this data into columns of an SQL table with column headings:

```
name,age,address,phone,result1,result2,result3...etc.
```

I've tried using SQL split functions but none I've tried seem to be compatible with Azure stream analytics job query. Could anyone provide any assistance as to how I can split my string into the appropriate tables? Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If your events are coming in with a CSV format, you don't have to do anything in your query to work with it. The trick is to set the correct serialisation for your input. When you create your IoT Hub input, set the serialisation to CSV:

[image: A screenshot highlighting the option you need to set]

This will work if your CSV message has the headers included in the message:

```
name,age,address,phone,result1,result2,result3
jon,41,111 treadmill lane,07831231123,aa,bb,123
```

It will show up in the input preview like so:
[image: input preview]

When the headers are present, you can use them in your queries.

```sql
SELECT
    name,
    age
INTO
    target
FROM
    [csv-input]
```